# Keras model on GPU: using Pandas in a custom loss function

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I'm trying to define the following (toy) custom loss function in Keras:

```py
def flexed_distance_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_df = pd.DataFrame(y_true, columns=my_columns)

    # do something with y_true_df

    return categorical_crossentropy(y_true_df.values, y_pred)
```

I'm running this model on GPU with `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()`.

Compiling the model generates no error, but when running `model.fit()`, the following error happens:

```
>>> y_true_df = pd.DataFrame(y_true, columns=my_columns)

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed:
AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

It seems that Pandas is trying to iterate over the tensor `y_true`, which is forbidden in graph mode (the preferred mode when training on GPU).

Must I understand that this is not possible to use Pandas within a loss function when training on GPU?

What would be some plausible alternatives, other than doing all the manipulations directly in TensorFlow itself? I'm doing quite some heavy re-indexing and merging and I can't begin to imagine the pain of doing all this in native TensorFlow code.

*Note:*

For reference, this is the kind of manipulation I'm trying to make:

```py
def flexed_distance_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_df = pd.DataFrame(y_true, columns=my_columns)
    y_true_custom = y_true_df.idxmax(axis=1).to_frame(name='my_name')

    y_true_df = pd.concat([y_true_custom, y_true_df], axis=1)

    y_true_df = y_true_df.where(y_true_df != 0, np.NaN)
    y_true_df = y_true_df.reset_index().set_index('my_name')

    nearby = y_true_df.fillna(pivoted_df.reindex(y_true_df.index)) \
                            .fillna(0) \
                            .set_index('index').sort_index()

    nearby = np.expm1(nearby).div(np.sum(np.expm1(nearby), axis=1), axis=0)

    y_true_flexed = nearby.values

    return categorical_crossentropy(y_true_flexed, y_pred)
```

Comment: Could you provide some example data and the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I realised that all I'm doing within the custom loss function is transforming `y_true`. In the real case, I'm transforming it based on some random number (`if random.random() > 0.1` then apply the transformation).

The most appropriate place to do this is not in a loss function, but in the batch generator instead.

```py
class BatchGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, indices, batch_size, mode):
        self.indices = indices
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.mode = mode

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.indices) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch = self.indices[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        X_batch = X[batch, :]
        y_batch = y[batch, :]

        if self.mode == 'train' and random.random() > 0.3:
            # pick y from regular batch
            return X_batch, y_batch
        else:
            # apply flex-distancing to y
            return X_batch, flex_distance_batch(y_batch)

batch_size = 512*4

train_generator = BatchGenerator(range(0, test_cutoff), batch_size, 'train')
test_generator = BatchGenerator(range(test_cutoff, len(y_df)), batch_size, 'test')
```

This way the transformations are applied directly from the batch generator, and Pandas is perfectly allowed here as we're dealing only with NumPy array on the CPU.